# How to deploy multiple java project with single file?

Tags: java, maven-3, war, executable-jar, ear

I have 6 maven projects that depended each other. I need to deploy all of them every time. Deploying 6 projects as seperated files are consuming my time and it's jar hell.

I'm looking for a way that will make my deployment easier with one single file. I dont know it's a jar file or war , ear i dont know.
Some of my projects fat jar, some of them one jar and the rest are assembler.

Any idea how i can solve this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to deploy a single jar, that contains all the jars (or whatever files) of all the projects?   Then use one of the maven plugins that builds all dependencies into a single jar.  [shade](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) and [assembly](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) both do it, there may be others.

You can also use the `ear` or `war` goals, but they have particular connotations and don't sound suitable for your aim.